# remove specific item from a json object

Tags: javascript, json

i am trying to remove some items in an json object list, the ones that have a specific group. My JSON looks like this.

```
var events = [
        {"id":"19","name":"sports","group":"1"},
        {"id":"20","name":"school","group":"2"},
        {"id":"21","name":"fun","group":"1"}
    ]
```

I tried this

```
for(var i in events)
    if(events[i].group == deleted_group)
        events.splice(i, 1);
```

But the problem of this, is that if i have to remove more items, it bugs out. Is there another easy way to to this ? I am open for sugestion even using `underscore.js` .

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var events = [
    {"id":"19","name":"sports","group":"1"},
    {"id":"20","name":"school","group":"2"},
    {"id":"21","name":"fun","group":"1"}
]

console.log(_.reject(events, function(event){ return event.group == '1'; }));
```

Comment: this works great, thank you very much and also to everyone on this topic

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel underscore solution is good indeed - I missed that you're using underscore in my answer. My answer is for people who don't want to use underscore and are interested in pure JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the "splice" function to remove elements from the array inside a for loop,
you need to shift your current index back when removing an item since the array is reindexed.

Also take a look at the array functions like "filter" for a more convenient way, read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype).

Comment: Filter seems to be the right answer to the question, however, [IE<9 doesn't support Array.prototype.filter](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` operator to delete objects (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
delete events[0]
```

The problem with `delete` is, that in your array, as a value of `events[0]` it will leave `undefined`.

So another way (the way I would choose for your simple example) is to just rewrite the array:

```
var temp_events = [];
for(var i in events)
    if(events[i].group != deleted_group)
        temp_events[temp_events.length] = events[i];
events = temp_events;
```

Executing splice in a for loop has complexity n^2 (where n is number of elements). Rewriting has linear complexity.